# Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC, when trying to deploy Contract from remix

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, json-rpc, polygon

I get the following error when i try to deploy my smart contract on remix onto the polygon chain:
[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"request":{"id":7159425935599,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params" ...
(It goes on with a bunch of numbers)

Can anyone help with his? The deployment onto the Mumbai Testnet worked fine

The full message:

> creation of MachkeinAuge errored: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"request":{"id":7159425935599,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["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"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"}}}}'

Comment: What code are you using to deploy the contract?